# How to use feature importance using random forest with pandas?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, neural-network, random-forest, feature-selection

I'm new here. I will be glad to know your suggestions of my question. I need to know which features of my data-set have the most importance. so, I used `SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100))` but the problem is I can't select columns which have the most importance in my data-base. 
I should use `selected_feat= X_train.columns[(sel.get_support())]` but the problem is numpy; numpy doesn't let me to use `X_train.columns[]`. I have tried to use `selected_feat= pd.DataFrame(columns=[(sel.get_support())])` but is doesn't work well.

is there anyone who could fix it?
data-set has 84 columns and all of them are numerical.
[part of my data-set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh3Bo.png)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Nov 23 11:42:37 2019

@author: Jacke
"""

from pandas import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy import*
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV,train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,accuracy_score,roc_curve,auc
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

##########################################################################################
db = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Jacke\Desktop\proposal\code\StackOverFlow\Test_F_Importance.csv")

X = db.iloc[:, 0:83]
y = db.iloc[:, 83]
m, n =  X.shape

X = preprocessing.scale(X)

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y)
encoded_y = encoder.transform(y)
y = to_categorical(encoded_y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

##########################################################################################
mlp = MLPClassifier()
parameter_space = {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(83,83,10), (20,40,20), (15,15,15)],
                   'activation': ['tanh', 'relu'],
                   'solver': ['sgd', 'adam'],
                   'alpha': [0.001,0.01, 0.05, 0.1],
                   'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive'],
                   'max_iter':[20,50,100]
                   }
clf = GridSearchCV(mlp, parameter_space, n_jobs=-1, cv=3,return_train_score=True)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Best parameters found:\n', clf.best_params_,clf.best_score_)
#########################################################################################
cvr = clf.cv_results_
df = DataFrame(cvr)
scores = df['mean_test_score']
h = df['param_hidden_layer_sizes']
alpha = df['param_alpha']
optim = df['param_solver']
l_rate = df['param_learning_rate']
activ = df['param_activation']
itr = df['param_max_iter']
dh = DataFrame({'Scores': scores,'Itraction':itr, 'Hidden_Layers': h, 'alpha': alpha ,
                'Solver':optim, 'Learning_Rate':l_rate, 'Activation':activ})

##########################################################################################
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(83, input_dim=n, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(83, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

##########################################################################################
m = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100, validation_split=0.5)
scoress = model.evaluate(X, y, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scoress[1]*100))
# save model and architecture to single file
model.save("model.h5")
model.save_weights("model.h5")

print("Saved model to disk")

########################Feature_Importance################################################
sel = SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100))
sel.fit(X_train, y_train)

# selected_feat= X_train.columns[(sel.get_support())]
selected_feat= pd.DataFrame(columns=[(sel.get_support())])
len(selected_feat)

print(selected_feat)


########################################################################################
# Plot training & validation accuracy values
plt.plot(m.history['acc'])
plt.plot(m.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('Training vs Test accuracy , DA')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Training acc', 'Validation acc'], loc='best')
#plt.show()
#plt.figure()
a = plt.savefig('Accuracy.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close(a)


# Plot training & validation loss values
plt.plot(m.history['loss'])
plt.plot(m.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Training vs Test Loss , DA')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Training loss', 'Validation loss'], loc='best')
#plt.show()
#plt.figure()
b = plt.savefig('Loss.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close(b)

##########################################################################################
y_score = model.predict(X_test)
org = zeros((y_test.shape[0]))
prd = zeros((y_score.shape[0]))
def decode(datum):
    return np.argmax(datum)
for i in range(y_score.shape[0]):
    prd[i] = decode(y_score[i])
for j in range(y_test.shape[0]):
    org[j] = decode(y_test[j])

confusion_matrix(org,prd)
print("Accuracy of MLP: ", "\n", confusion_matrix(org,prd))

f = open("output.txt", "a")
print('Accuracy Score : ' + str(accuracy_score(org,prd)), file=f)
f.close()

##########################################################################################

#model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
#model.fit(X,y)
#print(model.feature_importances_) #use inbuilt class feature_importances of tree based classifiers
##plot graph of feature importances for better visualization
#feat_importances = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
#feat_importances.nlargest(n).plot(kind='barh')
#plt.show()

##########################################################################################
def generate_results(y_test, y_score):
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, y_score)
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc)
    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
    plt.xlim([0.0, 1.05])
    plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic curve')
    #plt.show()
    plt.savefig('False and True comparison.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
    print('AUC: %f' % roc_auc)

#model = load_model('model.h5')
#model.summary()
#print("Accuracy of MLP: ", "\n", confusion_matrix(y_score,y_test))
print('Generating results')
generate_results(y_test[:, 0], y_score[:, 0])
```

here is my python code.
[here is my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nldQ8.png)

Answer (score 0):

The get_support method returns a mask - i.e. an array of TRUE and FALSE values that apply to your columns: 
[image]

Therefore you are creating an empty dataframe with columns named true and false. 
If you want a list with the name of the columns that are important, run:

```
[elem for elem in X_train.columns[sel.get_support]]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you Davide, but I have a problem if I use X_train.columns[]. here is the error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: Make them DFs. After you use train_test_split, run `X_train = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns = X.columns) ` and so on. If any of the subsequent calls to X_train (/y/test) need an array, just call .values to access the ndarray within

Answer (score 0):

X_train.columns[sel.get_support]]
how it selects only true columns from total features. i-e The get_support method returns a mask - i.e. an array of TRUE and FALSE values that apply to your columns:

Comment: please try to explain yourself better. use "i.e." less.

Comment: @OphirCarmi: I agree that najam should format his answer. Anyhow, this is no spelling contest and reviewing first posts is not meant for you to lecture on writing styles like 'i-e'. Sometimes I get the feeling that people reviewing forget that the sense of this is to motivate for better answers, not to point out writing styles that are not to your liking.